# accessing nested element in HTML by CLASS_NAME using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

3 buttons have the following class name

```
_55wr
```

nested class name for the specific button i want to access is

```
_54k8 _56bs _56b_ _56bx _56bu
```

i was previously writing this in my code

```
loginButton = driver.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.CLASS_NAME,"_54k8 _56bs _56b_ _56bx _56bu")))
loginButton.click()
```

but this is not working
can someone please tell me how can i access the nested class
while still ensuring visibility of the button

Comment: Could you share relevant HTML as well??

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot search element with compound class name using `By.CLASS_NAME`. Try following instead:

```
loginButton = driver.wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR,"._54k8._56bs._56b_._56bx._56bu")))
loginButton.click()
```